# What does "enim et" mean?

Tags: motto, grammar-identification, ecclesiastical-latin

A couple days ago, a friend sent me an excerpt from a new game, asking about a Latin phrase in it:

> *Contra Diabolus enim et alii Daemones*

(In the game, this is the motto of a group of Catholic monster hunters—so it's meant to be Church Latin, not Classical.)

The translation seems fairly straightforward: "Against the Devil and other Demons". I would have used *diabolum* in the accusative, but that's a separate matter.

What confused me, though, was the word *enim* in the middle. I would normally translate *enim* as "for" or "because". So what's it doing here, right before *et*? Is it just an error on the translator's part, or is this a usage of *enim* I'm not familiar with?

Comment: Enim follows its phrase; et precedes.  *Contra (Diabolum enim) (et alios Daemones)*

Comment: I keep seeing this in HNQ and reading it as 'What does "eminem" mean?'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A quick web search shows that the phrase 'Diabolus enim et alii Daemones' (without the *contra*) appears to originate from the Fourth Council of the Lateran (1215). The full sentence is *Diabolus enim et alii daemones a Deo quidem natura creati sunt boni, sed ipsi per se facti sunt mali*, which I would translate as something like, 'For the Devil and other demons were created by God (to be) good by nature, it's true, but they became, on their own, through their own agency, wicked.'

I suspect that whoever created the phrase for the game knew of this sentence, knew that *contra* means 'against', but didn't know that it requires a change of case or that *enim* doesn't really belong unless it's serving a connecting function; therefore, he or she just stuck *contra* at the beginning instead of changing to *contra Diabolum et alios daemones*.

Comment: Excellent! I think this is the right answer—am I correct in translating that sentence as "for the Devil and other demons, created by God, are indeed good by nature, but their deeds in and of themselves are evil"? I'm never sure when translating Church Latin if I'm missing some crucial nuance.

Comment: @Draconis, I updated the answer with my attempt at a translation – admittedly, a somewhat heavy-handed one.

Answer (score 6):

I would indeed expect the accusatives *Diabolum* and *alios* together with *contra*.
But there is a way to make the nominative work; then *contra* has to be read as an adverb, not a preposition (which would require accusative).
Ignoring the *enim*, the whole phrase could be read as "in front [of us are] the Devil and other Demons".

To make sense of *enim*, I think it modifies the entire motto, not just the second part.
It usually comes as the second word, but if the first two words are closely connected, it can come a little later.
This tight connection would make sense for me if *contra* was used as a preposition, but not so much in the adverbial use.
I find the position a little odd but not completely wrong.

As [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=enim&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) write, *enim* is a corroborative particle.
An apt English counterpart here might be "indeed".
Therefore I would read the whole as:

> In front [of us are] indeed the Devil and other Demons

However, this does feel a little odd.
*Enim* is in a weird place (and not even necessary in my opinion), and the use of *contra* strikes me as weird too.
The motto may well be a well-composed Latin motto, but it could also be a mistaken attempt at translating "Against the Devil and other Demons".